# How do I get the text to remain in textarea after saving it with php?

Tags: php, textarea

I am making a notes page. The user can add notes in a textarea and press save and it is saved into a database. Once you press save the note is no longer there and will clear out. I want the note to still be there when the page reloads. I have done some research in this area and haven't found much luck. Is there any way to press save yet leave the text on screen?

Comment: Just echo out the form data after the page loads

Comment: Save the textarea data and then just print it back.

Comment: Show the code. Then only we are able to sort out the problem

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615214/post-back-in-php-or-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler alternative would be the following one.

```
<textarea>
  <?php  
    print (!empty($_POST["notes"]) ? filter_var($_POST["notes"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : null); 
  ?>
</textarea>
```

`$_POST` should be sanitized for malicious inputs, but that's a simple example which will get you running as a start.

Answer (score 2):

For that, you need to check, if any post values are sets inside the `<textarea>`

```
<textarea name="notes">

   <?php 
      if( isset($_POST['notes']) )
       echo $_POST['notes'];
   ?>

</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

After submitting the form just echo the post value of the texarea. Something line this if you want to show that in textarea

```
<textarea name="context"><?php echo $_POST['context'];?></textarea>
```

Comment: or, maybe try: `eval($_POST['context'])`... really, please do! And supply the www so I could HACK you ;)

Comment: Unamata Sanatarai is right. Don't do this!!! It's very unsafe. Always sanitize user input.